# Altering value of one column based on another in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

So lets say I have this table: There are a couple things I want to do.

[image]

Comment: UPDATE t SET c = value WHERE conditions

Comment: Your question has been edited to remove all the content except the picture. Can you please edit it again?

Answer (score 2):

Use an update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET PRICE = -1.0*PRICE
WHERE SIDE = 'SELL';
```

Comment: Price seems to be a string instead!

Comment: @cdaiga Then my first advice would be to create a new decimal column to store the price data.  It would do no good stored as text.

Comment: Yes, but the data presented seems to be a string, as there's a $ infront of it.

Comment: It's currency, I'm using MS Access. Thanks for the answer, I'm new to SQL to this is all learning to me.

Comment: @cdaiga It is probably a `Currency` type column, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the price is a numeric field.

```
UPDATE yourTable SET PRICE=-1.0*PRICE WHERE SIDE='SELL';
```

Comment: How do you know which database the OP is using?

Comment: The dollar sign in the prices!

Comment: The string concatenation operator in Access is `&`, not `+`, and the OP has already revealed the price column to be a numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for multiplying, and you could take care of previous updates:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET PRICE = -PRICE
WHERE [SIDE] = 'SELL' AND PRICE > 0;
```